# iOS 4.3 or later will not be available to Verizon iPhone users?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Right after I upload my binary over to Apple in iTunesConnect, it appears this message,

"The binary uploaded for the latest version of this app indicates that iOS 4.3 or later is required. Apps that require iOS 4.3 or later will not be available to Verizon iPhone users. If this app could be compatible with earlier iOS versions, you may want to reject the binary and upload a new one that indicates the earliest compatible iOS."

What to do so that I can have my app reach as many as customers possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Find those 4.3 exclusive methods and look for alternatives available for 4.0
In future projects, try to develop thinking on a reasonable iOS version.

Today to develop with a base of 4.0 it's more than reasonable.

Comment: How do I change the version exactly so that it won't pop this message? Thank you so much, I am new to Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, if you wait a week, the Verizon iPhone will be on iOS5 and you can use iOS4.3+ APIs.

Comment: what's APIs? Sorry I am so new to this...